# Zend Framework: How can I add JavaScript element after the scripts in head?

Tags: php, javascript, zend-framework

I have a partial which loads all common links and styles in head and I use setScript in other pages for local scripts. I want to add the following script which is located in my view/scripts after other scripts but zf appends it at first:

```
<? $this->headScript()->setScript('$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#birthdate").datepicker();
        });', 
    $type = 'text/javascript') ?>
```

which leads to following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#birthdate").datepicker();
        });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.dcmegamenu.1.3.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
```

but I want:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.dcmegamenu.1.3.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#birthdate").datepicker();
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try calling:

```
<? $this->headScript()->appendScript('$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#birthdate").datepicker();
        });', 
    $type = 'text/javascript') ?>
```

Try adding your other files using:

```
<? $this->setScript()
->prependFile('/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js')
->prependFile('/js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js') 
->prependFile('/js/jquery.dcmegamenu.1.3.3.min.js') 
->prependFile('/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js') ;
?>
```

Comment: How are you adding the other scripts to the header?

Comment: Here is the code: <?= $this->setScript()->setFile('/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js')
        ->setFile('/js/jquery.dcmegamenu.1.3.3.min.js')
        ->setFile('/js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js')
        ->setFile('/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js'); ?>

Comment: @Brian Fisher do you know maybe how to do this in codeigniter? Or can you explain me how setScript()->setFile() is working?